# Can $\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx<\infty$ imply $\int_0^1 |f(x)|dx<\infty$, if $f$ unbounded near $0$.

Tags: integration

> Can $\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx<\infty$ imply $\int_0^1 |f(x)|dx<\infty$, if $f$ unbounded near $0$.

The converse is wrong, since $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ is an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is immediate from Cauchy-Schwarz (assuming $f$ is real-valued):
$$
\left(\int_0^1 \lvert f(x)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^2
\leq\int_0^1 \lvert f(x)\rvert^2\,\mathrm{d}x\cdot\int_0^1 \,\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1 f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$
Or you can use AM-GM pointwise and integrate:
$$
\lvert f(x)\rvert\leq\frac{1+ f(x)^2}{2}
\Rightarrow
\int_0^1\lvert f(x)\rvert\,\mathrm{d}x\leq\frac{1+\int_0^1 f(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x}{2}
$$